# Eliminate the Career tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we please eliminate the [career](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career) tag? I just can't imagine a question where that tag is appropriate and still be on topic but not totally subjective (although the subjective vote has now been renamed).

While looking at this one I noticed something I wasn't aware of previously. When viewing one of the questions, on the right hand side it lists the tags and the number of questions each has. When I click the tag only two questions show up. I'm guessing that's because the other 27 have already been closed. Can someone confirm that assumption please.

Comment: I'm gunna wait for others to weigh in first before doing anything, but there are 29 questions for [tag:career], and only 4 have been closed (yet), although the majority probably should be.

Comment: @Mark, any idea why only 2 showed up when I clicked on the tag?

Comment: @John - nope, no idea

Comment: @john you had the FAQ tab highlighted rather than newest.

Comment: @Iain, no I didn't, but I think you're close. I just went to the tags and searched for "career". I then clicked the tag and just two questions appeared and it turned out the unanswered tab has highlighted. The odd thing is that one of those questions does have an answer. I think I'll just stick to the front page in future. At least that seems to work the way I expect it to.

Comment: @john see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I found a useful answer to a question with a `career` tag - and it's yours.  http://serverfault.com/a/130354/78219
please see 
http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5270/why-does-career-tag-exist

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are only 32 of these. Does the community want to weigh in on which questions in this tag, if any, should be saved?

Comment: I've gone over them and removed the `career` and `career-development` tags because they were completely unrelated to the question (which I've also voted to close as not constructive). The rest can all go in my opinion.

Comment: Oops. It was only one question where I removed those tags.