# why does career tag exist?

Tags: discussion, career-development

similar question:
http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1666/eliminate-the-career-tag

I have been searching serverfault, security.stackexchange, programmers.stackexchange, workplace.stackexchange for the past week for career questions, but none of these site accept career questions in the faq.

I have asked several questions already, which have been closed.

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31215/what-are-the-more-physical-job-classes
- https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/which-site-to-locate-career-question
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/physically-demanding-job-classes-in-information-technology

I finally found a useful answer at [What are some IT jobs where you don't sit at a desk for 8-10hrs a day?](https://serverfault.com/questions/130141/what-are-some-it-jobs-where-you-dont-sit-at-a-desk-for-8-10hrs-a-day/130149#130149) but that was also closed.

So if career questions aren't acceptable on any of these stackexchange sites

1. why does the [career](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career) even exist?
2. why not a site where career questions *can* be asked?
3. if you [sum](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) all the `career` questions across sites, how many are there?

Comment: Some career style questions might be appropriate over on workplace.  Most others are probably more appropriate for places like LOPSA reddit/r/sysadmin.

Comment: @Zoredache please look at the 3rd link I posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Because people who have the privilege created it before we decided that [career](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career) questions are really Not Constructive and we haven't gotten round to tidying it up. Thanks for bringing it to our attention again.
2. If you really want one go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).
3. [>49](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career?sort=newest&pagesize=50).

Comment: We do have a stack exchange site where [tag:career] questions can be asked - [workplace.se]. (Not for "career advice", but great for "How should I deal with this backbiting office politicking that goes on in the working world?")